# What does a British person mean by: "Yer a right sausage, you!"?

Tags: british-english

I heard this said by a native British speaker in a video:

> Yer a right sausage, you!

What does this mean? My *guess* is that it means something like:

> You are a truly stupid/silly person!

Am I right? Close? Wrong?

Comment: Rightish and close enough, but it's probably meant affectionately, while the use of *truly* in your gloss rather makes that quite nasty.

Comment: Regional or rural dialect. A child may be called a 'silly sausage'. It doesn't mean 'stupid person'. At most, 'slightly silly, and not in a bad way'.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sausage) has: **sausage** 2 *British informal* Used as an affectionate form of address, especially to a child.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. Alliterative ***silly sausage*** goes back [at least a century](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Silly+sausage+I+must+be%22), and although undoubtedly "whimsical", it's not confined to contexts where it's addressed to a child.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I didn't mean to imply that the phrase may only be used with children. It is decidedly whimsical and affectionate.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Yes - it's *whimsical* ([yah silly ***puddin'**!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+silly+pudding%22) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers My mother used to call me a _soppy ha'p'orth_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I was a *daft apeth* for years before I realised it was a *coinage* reference, and not some kind of diminutive of *ape,* as in often affectionate *cheeky **monkey***